# On MySql Is it possible to GRANT Select to ALL users?

Tags: mysql

My question is simple, can I GRANT permission to ALL (as in any user with any pwd coming from any machine) users ?

- I know it COULD BE problematic in some cases. But ours is a demo database, with users unknown. So please spare us the rod.
- From what I know and what I have tried the Answer is NO, we can not do it.  I am posting this question to confirm my understanding.

AFAIK, we can't. Is there a way to hack around this  ?

Comment: This is an extremely bad idea. Even with just `SELECT` privileges, users can run queries that will deliberately bog down your database (like `SELECT BENCHMARK(large number, MD5(1))`). Don't do it.

Comment: If you don't care about security for this database, just give everyone the same username.

Comment: @Barmar that is what I am currently doing.  While it may not be difficult to tell your director to use a different user/pwd than his  CORP user/pwd,  it is a line of communication I want to reduce. 
You know how it is. :)

Comment: If you want to GRANT something to ANY AUTHENTICATED user, have a look at this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23815765/how-to-grant-select-on-tablename-to-public-in-mysql)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As people have said in the comments - this is probably a bad idea. But, I thought, why not have a crack and see how it can be done.

The most simple place to start would be to create a MySQL user without a username:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO ''@'%' IDENTIFIED BY '';
```

This will let you login with any username - and a blank password. This might be what some people are looking for - but it sounds like you want any username any password.

To do that - I suggest using [mysql-proxy](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/mysql-proxy/). I would download the source code. If you're on Ubuntu then you will need the following packages to build it:

```
apt-get install libmysqlclient-dev \
    pkg-config \
    lua5.1 liblua5.1-0-dev liblua5.1-0 \
    libglib2.0-dev \
    libevent-1.4-2 libevent1-dev
```

If you do compile it then you'll need to run /sbin/ldconfig afterwards as root.

Then we can write a lua script to set the username and password for every connection. The mysql-proxy client has some example scripts, but the relevant examples/tutorial-scramble.lua file is old and doesn't work with the current version. You can use the following script:

```
local CLIENT_PROTOCOL_41       = 512    -- New 4.1 protocol
local CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION = 32768  -- New 4.1 authentication

local MYSQL_AUTH_CAPABILITIES  = ( CLIENT_PROTOCOL_41 + CLIENT_SECURE_CONNECTION )

local password = assert(require("mysql.password"))
local proto = assert(require("mysql.proto"))

function read_auth()
        local c = proxy.connection.client
        local s = proxy.connection.server

        local challenge = (s.scramble_buffer):sub(1,20)

        local default_username = "foo"
        local default_password = "bar"

        proxy.queries:append(1,
                proto.to_response_packet({
                        username = default_username,
                        response = password.scramble(challenge, password.hash(default_password)),
                        charset  = 8, -- default charset
                        database = c.default_db,
                        max_packet_size = 1 * 1024 * 1024,
                        server_capabilities = MYSQL_AUTH_CAPABILITIES
                })
        )

        return proxy.PROXY_SEND_QUERY
end
```

Save this as any-user-any-pass.lua or something. Then you will need to create the user in the database which I refer to in the script (username foo, password bar):

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'foo'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'bar';
```

Then we can start up mysql-proxy - we will connect it to the local mysql server on port 3306 and it will listen on port 3307. Use a command similar to this:

```
mysql-proxy --proxy-lua-script=`pwd`/any-user-any-pass.lua \
    --proxy-backend-addresses=localhost:3306 \
    --proxy-address=localhost:3307
```

Test it out in a different terminal:

```
ubuntu@test:~$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3306 -u ANYTHING -pSOMETHING
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'ANYTHING'@'localhost' (using password: YES)
ubuntu@test:~$ mysql -h 127.0.0.1 -P 3307 -u ANYTHING -pSOMETHING
Welcome to the MySQL monitor.  Commands end with ; or \g.
Your MySQL connection id is 752
Server version: 5.5.29-0ubuntu1 (Ubuntu)

Copyright (c) 2000, 2012, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.

Oracle is a registered trademark of Oracle Corporation and/or its
affiliates. Other names may be trademarks of their respective
owners.

Type 'help;' or '\h' for help. Type '\c' to clear the current input statement.

mysql> SELECT CURRENT_USER();
+----------------+
| CURRENT_USER() |
+----------------+
| foo@localhost  |
+----------------+
1 row in set (0.00 sec)

mysql>
```

As you can see - first I test connecting straight to MySQL - it rejects the ANYTHING/SOMETHING credentials. Then I connect to the MySQL proxy on 3307 and it lets me straight in because the lua script is changing the username and password the connection is using.

Comment: That was awessome !
+1  also for the fact that you understood, that I would prefer SOMETHING as password not NULL/"" .  Since that NULL/"" would still mean I will have to tell everyone that you will have to leave that field blank. :)

Comment: I think  SO  is bad cuz, they dont provide follow you feature. I would have totally followed all your posts. Now I have to just bookmark your profile page.  :)

Comment: Thanks for asking an interesting question :-)