# How to GRANT SELECT ON tablename to PUBLIC in MySQL

Tags: mysql

I am new to MySQL. I am trying to figure out how to make a table publicly readable to all authenticated users.  In Oracle I would say `grant select on tablename to public`.  This syntax does not work with MySQL and I cannot figure out the equivalent syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per [MySQL Documentation](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/grant.html)

> MySQL does not support wildcards in user names. To refer to an
>   anonymous user, specify an account with an empty user name with the
>   GRANT statement:

`GRANT ALL ON test.* TO ''@'localhost'`

> In this case, any user who connects from the local host with the
>   correct password for the anonymous user will be permitted access, with
>   the privileges associated with the anonymous-user account.

So you can grant `select` to anyone from `localhost` like

```
grant select on tablename to ''@'localhost'
```

(OR)

You can grant all users from a specific domain. Excerpt from MySQL doc

> You can specify wildcards in the host name. For example,
>   user_name@'%.example.com' applies to user_name for any host in the
>   example.com domain, and user_name@'192.168.1.%' applies to user_name
>   for any host in the 192.168.1 class C subnet.
>
> The simple form user_name is a synonym for user_name@'%'.

Answer (score 0):

The equivalent SQL syntax in MySQL is:

```
GRANT SELECT ON [database].[table] TO '[username]'@'[IP address]';
```

If you haven't already created a user, then it is:

```
GRANT SELECT ON [database].[table] TO '[username]'@'[IP address]' IDENTIFIED BY '[password]';
```

Don't forget to run `FLUSH PRIVILEGES;` after `GRANT` as well!

If you don't have a database created yet, then you will also need to run `CREATE DATABASE '[database]';` before running the `GRANT` query.

Here's an example for creating a database called "mydb" and allowing user "jblow" with password "password123" to execute `SELECT` statements on any table from the local machine only:

```
CREATE DATABASE 'mydb';
GRANT SELECT ON mydb.* TO 'jblow'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'password123';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Also, if you want to allow multiple users, then just repeat the `GRANT` statement for each user.

Comment: Per my understanding, OP means grant privilege to all authenticated users and not to some specific one.