# how does MySQL grant privileges to all users on mysqlworkbench

Tags: mysql, mysql-workbench

I want to grant privileges to all users on MySQLworkbench. And I try use "to public", but it shows errors.How to grant privileges to all users? Help me,please.Thanks.

Code:

```
grant select
on SQL_System.SPJ
to public
@localhost;
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [On MySql Is it possible to GRANT Select to ALL users?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20157429/on-mysql-is-it-possible-to-grant-select-to-all-users)

Comment: @Raymond Nijland it doesn't work .